# XSL Select min DateTime for specific parent nodes using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, min

I have the following XML document:

```
<Document>
    <A>
        <StartDateTime>2017-01-01T08:00</StartDateTime>
        <EndDateTime>2017-01-01T09:00</EndDateTime>
    </A>
    <B>
        <StartDateTime>2017-01-01T06:00</StartDateTime>
        <EndDateTime>2017-01-01T08:00</EndDateTime>
    </B>
    <C>
        <StartDateTime>2017-01-12T08:00</StartDateTime>
        <EndDateTime>2017-01-12T09:00</EndDateTime>
    </C>
    <D>
        <StartDateTime>2017-01-07T08:00</StartDateTime>
        <EndDateTime>2017-01-07T09:00</EndDateTime>
    </D>
</Document>
```

I would like to find the minimum StartDateTime, but only parent nodes A and D should be taken into account. B and C should be ignored. The resulting minimum value should be put in a variable.

How can I achieve this using XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Sort `/Document/A/StartDateTime | /Document/D/StartDateTime` and output only the first item (in ascending order) or the last (in descending order). While XSLT 1.0 has no support for a particular date or date/time data type, the format you have is sortable as a text/string which should work fine (unless you also have data with timezone information).

Comment: Your hint did the trick. Thanks, Martin!